# How to reference object key's value using a string type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a few object types defined in `RigidbodyShape`:

```js
export type RigidbodyShape = { type: 'sphere', radius: number; } |
{ type: 'cube', size: { width: number, height: number, depth: number; }; }
```

I would like to get the type by passing `cube`, `sphere`, etc. to the generic found within `MyClass`.

```js
export interface RigidbodyOptions {
  shape: RigidbodyShape<T>;
}

class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    public readonly rigidbody: RigidbodyRef<'cube'>
  }
}

export class RigidbodyRef<T> {
  options!: T;
}
```

So, how can I set the type of `options` to by referencing the type in the object by passing the string?

```js
{ type: 'cube', size: { width: number, height: number, depth: number; }; }
```